# laravel 9.x passing controller variable to another file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass form values on my PagesController.php to HelloMail.php After passing variables it will send mail.
I'm new to laravel tried to make some research about it and read the older questions but none of them contains proper answer for my question.

Problem: Undefined variable on HelloEmail.php => $emailSender - $emailSubject - $emailBody

Do I need to change my route for this? or is it makeable on controllers?

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/message',[App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::class,'getData'])->name('message');
Route::view('message','message');

Route::get('/send-email', [App\Http\Controllers\EmailController::class, 'sendEmail']);
```

**PagesController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function getData(Request $Req)
    {
        $emailSender = $Req->input('emailSender');
        $emailSubject = $Req->input('emailSubject');
        $emailBody = $Req->input('emailBody');
       
    }
}
```

**HelloEmail.php**

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use app\Http\Controllers\PagesController;

class HelloEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($emailSender)
                    ->body('$emailSubject')
                    ->subject('$emailBody');
        }
}
```

**EmailController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\HelloEmail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $toAddress= "email@example.com";

        Mail::to($toAddress)->send(new HelloEmail);
        dd("Email is sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little untidy for me, do you need to send form submitted data in email?

Comment: Yes. So user will send a form which contains their email address, topic and body. I couldn't connect the button to send mail. That's why I'm trying to transfer the form values to HelloMail.php. I hope that's more clear.

Comment: It is easy you can make a route type of post and make a form with fields includeding csrf token and redirect form that route using action attributes, in route closure or wherever you want just pass the values to email template and then send, any ambiguity?

Comment: Thank you @MANSOORKOCHY can you give me an example code for it or document. I want to inspect it all. It will be key for me.

Comment: I apologize for code for sure I will share a link with you follow it step by step alongside Laravel office documentation,

Comment: https://www.positronx.io/laravel-contact-form-example-tutorial/

Comment: @MANSOORKOCHY Could you check my last question? I tried to make it but failed as expected...

Comment: sure, but please help my find your last question :)

Comment: @MANSOORKOCHY Oh sorry lol https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71808087/laravel-9-x-contact-form-cant-connect-to-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you looking for from sending emails from separate requests, but you can pass variables to HelloEmail class from the constructor

Example

**HelloEmail**

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use app\Http\Controllers\PagesController;

class HelloEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    private $emailSender;
    private $emailSubject;
    private $emailBody;
    
    
    public function __construct($emailSender, $emailSubject, $emailBody)
    {
        $this->emailSender = $emailSender;
        $this->emailSubject = $emailSubject;
        $this->emailBody = $emailBody;
    }
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->emailSender)
            ->body($this->emailBody)
            ->subject($this->emailSubject);
    }
}
```

and in **EmailController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\HelloEmail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $toAddress= "email@example.com";

        Mail::to($toAddress)->send(new HelloEmail('sender@example.com', 'email subject !', 'the body'));
        dd("Email is sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

I hope it's useful

Comment: Thank you yes it is helpful. I learned how to use the __construct but I have to work on it. I will be digging into it tomorrow.