# Laravel 9.x Contact form can't connect to class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a contact form. Main idea is user will send data, I will save the data to database, I will get the data from database, I will send the data as an email.

I was following a tutorial -> https://www.positronx.io/laravel-contact-form-example-tutorial/

When I tried to reach classes on my controller it can not find it.

[Controller says this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1vLB.png)

[But I have the file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRv9z.png)

When I run the code I'm having this ->
[Cannot instantiate abstract class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z5Wc.png)

**ContactUsFormController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Models\Contact;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ContactUsFormController extends Controller
{
    //create contact form
    public function createForm(Request $req){
        return view('contact');
    }
    //store contact form data
    public function ContactUsForm(Request $req){
        //form validation 
        $this->validate($req,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required | email',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);
        //store data in database
        Model::create($req->All());
        //send mail to admin
        Mail::send('mail',array(
            'name' => $req->get('name'),
            'email' => $req->get('email'),
            'subject' => $req->get('subject'),
            'message' => $req->get('message')
        ),function($message) use ($req){
            $message->from($req->email);
            $message->to('MyMail@example.com','admin')->subject($req->get('subject'));
        });
        return back()->with('success', 'We have recieved your message');
    }
}
```

This one making me thinking. In the tutorial he didn't write a single code into this file but still calling a class from there.
**app\Mails\contact.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
class contact extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
  public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('view.name');
    }
}
```

**app\Models\Contact.php**

```
namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Contact extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'subject', 'message'];

}
```

Do I have a typo? What I am missing?
Sorry I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue you call `Model::create();` model is just an abstract class, not your concrete model

replace

```
Model::create($req->All());
```

with

```
Contact::create($req->All());
```

also change `namespace App\Mail;` in your Contact model to namespace `App\Models;`

to know more information about Mail facade check this

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#sending-mail

I hope it's useful

Comment: It still says undefined type app\Models\Contact for `Contact::create($req->All());`  I start thinking about maybe is that something about namespaces? what do you think? Because it's using the same namespace for both of the contact files.

Comment: @NervousDev yes it is, change `namespace App\Mail;` in your Contact model to `namespace App\Models;`

Comment: Okay I understand the logic. I have one more question. Since I'm calling a class `Mail::send(')` on `app\Mails\contact.php` I don't have a class named `send()` How to I add make that how is it working on the tutorial?

Comment: send() is a method not class also you use Mail facade not Contact mailable check this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#sending-mail

Comment: It didn't completely fixed my problem because of my unfinished code but if you edit your answer with namespaces and mentioned futures I can accept as an answer.

Comment: I edit my answer, the course didn't use Contact Mail class so I think you will not gonna need it

Comment: Yes I think so. I decided to learn more about the mvc structure before diving into this kind of stuff. Thank you for all the help.